# Jdbc scripts giving duplicated values

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am working with namedParameterJdbcTemplate and sql scripts in  spring mvc project
my when i perfrom i get all orders from db i get a result of 14 but i have only 7 written insert statements ,what i tried doing was clean install and i removed the data from data-scripts and left only one , when i ran my test it shows two data's .

```
 @Override
    public final Collection<OrderWithTruckCodeDto> getAllOrdersWithTruckCode() {
        LOGGER.debug("getAllOrdersWithTruckCode()");
        Collection<OrderWithTruckCodeDto> ordersDto = namedParameterJdbcTemplate
                .getJdbcOperations()
                .query(selectAllWithTruckCodeSql, new OrderWithTruckCodeDtoRowMapper());
        return ordersDto;
    }
```

my scipts look like this

```
INSERT INTO orderz (petrolQty, orderDate ,truckId )
VALUES (13, '2006-01-21',3);
INSERT INTO orderz (petrolQty , orderDate , TRUCKID )
VALUES (13.0, '2006-1-21', 3);
```

my test

```
  @Test
    public void getAllOrderWithTruckCodeDto() {
        Collection<OrderWithTruckCodeDto> orders =
                orderDao.getAllOrdersWithTruckCode();
        Assert.assertFalse(orders.isEmpty());
        Assert.assertTrue(orders.size() == 7);
    }
```

I wam working with h2 db , and when try this out on h2 console everything works fine

These are my queries

```
order.selectAllWithTruckCode =  SELECT o.orderId,  o.orderDate, petrolQty, t.truckCode \
FROM orderz o left join truck t ON (o.truckId = t.truckId) \
group by o.orderId

order.filterByDate = SELECT o.orderId,  o.orderDate, petrolQty, t.truckCode \
FROM orderz o left join truck t ON (o.truckId = t.truckId) \
where o.orderDate >=  :start and o.orderDate <= :end \
group by o.orderId
```

Comment: selectAllWithTruckCodeSql what is in this variable, also check property file how it handles the -- ?

Comment: Is ordersDto  0 before running query

Comment: Yes, please, could you show us the query?

Comment: So where is your SQL query?

Comment: I will ad the queries now but i solved look at my answer but i dont know why create table if not exists could cause this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name look at my answer but i have posted the query for any further suggestions

Answer (score 1):

My Create-script looked like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orderz (
  orderId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  petrolQty DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  orderDate timestamp NOT NULL,
  truckId INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (orderId),
  FOREIGN KEY (truckId) REFERENCES truck(truckId)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
```

when i changed to this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orderz;
CREATE TABLE orderz (
  orderId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  petrolQty DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  orderDate timestamp NOT NULL,
  truckId INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (orderId),
  FOREIGN KEY (truckId) REFERENCES truck(truckId)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The problem was solved , but i dont know why this could create dublicates

Answer (score 0):

Probably filters out the

```
--
```

so you're just executing the statement you have in comments as well

Comment: thats not the issue , i did that i deleted completely left just one and it say 2, and both in the result set are identical